Roman to integer
def romanToInt(s):
        symbol= ['I','V','X','L','C','D','M']
        value= [1,5,10,50,100,500,1000]
        dic= {k:v for k,v in zip(symbol, value)}
        sums=0
        string= [i for i in range(len(s))]
        for i in string:
            if s[i] in ['I','X','C']:
                left_index= list(dic.keys()).index(s[i])
                next_symbol= list(dic.keys())[left_index + 1]
                next2_symbol= list(dic.keys())[left_index + 2]

                if i < len(s) and (s[i]== next_symbol or s[i]== next2_symbol):
                    sums+= dic[s[i+1]] -dic[s[i]]
                    string.remove(i)
                    string.remove(i+1)
                elif i < len(s) and (s[i]!= next_symbol or s[i]!= next2_symbol):
                    sums+= dic[s[i]]
                elif i== len(s):
                    sums+= dic[s[i]]
            else:
                sums+= dic[s[i]]

        return sums

I have some problem with my code when i put some roman numerals together such IV, IX, XL etc , for example "MCMXCIV", the output is 2216 instead of 1994. Need some help

The rule with Roman numerals is if a large value is preceded by a smaller, the small value is subtracted from the larger. So in the above sequence its 1000 (M) + (CM) (1000 - 100) + (XC)  (100 -10) + (IV) (5 - 1) = 1000 + 900 + 90 + 4..

Does this answer your question? Converting Roman Numerals to integers in python

Yes, but i'm trying to fix my solution.

I notice you're modifying the string that you're iterating. I don't know what effect it'll have in this particular case, but generally not a good idea.

There's nothing wrong with your code except a logical error, you are handling the subtraction in the loop for multiple I,X and Cs but this does not account for the subtraction with the rest of the letters. So instead handle the subtraction for V,L,D and M in the same loop as well.
symbol = ['I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M']
    value = [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]
    dic = {k: v for k, v in zip(symbol, value)}
    
    sums = 0
    i = 0  
    
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] in ['I', 'X', 'C']:
            current_val = dic[s[i]]
            
            # don't need lists since strings can be indexed
            if i < len(s) - 1 and (s[i:i+2] in ['IV', 'IX', 'XL', 'XC', 'CD', 'CM']):# definitely skipped a few cases
                sums += dic[s[i+1]] - current_val
                i += 2  
            else:
                sums += current_val
                i += 1
        else:
            sums += dic[s[i]]
            i += 1
        
    return sums

But yeah the other answers are definitely better code wise since it's easier to handle roman numerals right to left since you only need to keep track of the next input.(though best case is always using an existing solution)

You could use the 'roman' module if you don't want to create your own solution.
import roman

n = "MCMXCIV"

print(roman.fromRoman(n))

Prints: 1994

Thank you, but i want to stick with my solution

def romanToInt(s):
    symbol = ['I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M']
    value = [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]
    dic = {k: v for k, v in zip(symbol, value)}
    sums = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if i < len(s) - 1 and dic[s[i]] < dic[s[i + 1]]:
            sums += dic[s[i + 1]] - dic[s[i]]
            i += 2
        else:
            sums += dic[s[i]]
            i += 1
    return sums


Correct version with while loop
